# Groups with very unequal sizes

Tags: generalized-linear-model, sample-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I want to compare means of the data of two human populations, group A has 12,400 (91.7%) subjects and group B has 1118 (8.3%). These are further subdivided to groups A1 (7598, 93.8%), B1 (499, 6.4%), and A2 (4802, 88.8%), B2 (619, 11.4%). Data are log normally distributed and I am using Mann-Whitney's test and generalised linear equations to compare A1 to B1, and A2 to B2.

I know Mann-Whitney does not require equal sample sizes, but does this include such a large difference in sample sizes? Also, I hope it is OK to use the generalised linear equations.

Could you please post an article that I can refer to for the two methods in case they are appropriate to use?